# Building an IPA archive for TestFlight distribution

Tags: ipa, testflight

I am having the following issue, with Xcode 4.2, trying to create an IPA archive to distribute with TestFlight.

Everything seems fine until I build the archive.

When I want to upload this archive I get the following message:

"Invalid IPA: The keychain-access-group in the embedded.mobileprovision and your binary don't match."

What does this exactly mean?

I have looked on the net various things about this issue, but nothing drove me to a solution at this point. I also tried what I could think of, but with no success.

Can anyone point me to a solution?

Thank you in advance, for any tip.

Comment: Do you have a distribution profile set up for the particular identifier of this app?

Comment: I'm having this same thing too after creating a new target and then trying to distribute it. Was wondering if you were able to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem. It was caused by having the wrong release code signing identity in the target's build settings.

Comment: Also you won't need an entitlements file.

Comment: Yep, thanks, same here. I had updated some certificates, and XCode then reset my certs to the wrong ones throughout. You don't want to get into entitlements files if you don't have to...

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused by not changing the build identifier and access group in the entitlements file. Make sure you change these in the entitlements file. More information on how to do this can be found [here](http://www.karlmonaghan.com/2012/08/09/invalid-ipa-the-keychain-access-group-in-the-embedded-mobileprovision-and-your-binary-dont-match/)

Comment: And if you don't use an entitlements file... ?